# Circle through focii of ellipse

Tags: circles, conic-sections, coordinate-systems

A circle passes through the focii of an ellipse.
Circle intersects ellipse at points A and B. Tangents and normals are drawn to the ellipse at A & B such that tangents intersect at P and normals intersect at Q. Then what is PQ is equal to ?

Is this a property that when a circle passes through focii of ellipse, the tangents meet at P and normals meet at Q and PQ is one of the diameters of the circle?

Comment: Which points of intersection are actually P and Q?  The circle can intersect the ellipse at up to four points.

Comment: This is a nice construction. Can you use the fact that if the foci are $F_1,F_2$ and $E$ is a point on the ellipse, then $EF_1$ and $EF_2$ make equal angles with the tangent to the ellipse at $E$? (That is, a ray from $F_1$ reflects to $F_2$.) That is, is this a fact already proved by or for you? Or would you have to prove that fact first?

Comment: HINT. The bisector of an inscribed angle also bisects the intercepted arc.

Comment: @DavidK that is already proved. This was actually an MCQ question from a mock test I had.  And I'm trying to understand what property of ellipse/ circle is being used and how is it happening. So how do i proceed after the ray reflection

Comment: @Aretino Im sorry but i do not understand the hint. Is it a fact that the tangents and normals meet on the circle ? Im really confused. And if possible could you please give a derivation/proof based on the question?

Comment: You must observe, first of all, that $P$ and $Q$, by symmetry, lie on the minor axis (produced if necessary). And minor axis bisects arc $F_1F_2$ (the arc subtended by foci on the circle). And normals at $A$ and $B$ also bisect that arc.

Comment: Actually you don't even need the symmetry argument. The construction works even if the circle intersects the ellipse in four points and we choose two points that are on the same side of the minor axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the ellipse with foci $F_1$ and $F_2$ as shown below,
with a circle through $F_1$ and $F_2$ intersecting the ellipse at $A$.
Furthermore we have the tangent to the ellipse at $A$,
intersecting the circle at $S$,
and the perpendicular to the tangent at $A$,
intersecting the circle at $R$.

[image]

Knowing that $\angle F_1AR = \angle \angle F_2AR,$
what can you conclude about circular arcs $F_1R$ and $F_2R$?

Knowing that $\angle RAS$ is a right angle, what can you conclude about the line segment $RS$?

It can be shown that $R$ and $S$ are the points where the minor axis of the ellipse intersects the circle.
Therefore if we repeat this construction at another intersection point of the ellipse and circle, for example $B$ in this figure, the tangent and perpendicular lines will again intersect the circle at two points on the minor axis of the ellipse, which therefore are the same points $R$ and $S,$ which therefore are the two points $P$ and $Q.$

In this case the construction works equally well at any of the four intersection points between the circle and ellipse.
If we alter the shape or positions of the ellipse and/or circle so that there are only two intersections, the construction is still valid for those two points.